# Keep a single instance of WebDriver in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, nunit

I am using the latest version of NUnit 3 with Selenium 3 in VB2015.  I currently have a class that only creates a driver, a base class that does setup and tear down, and some classes that actually performs the tests.  I want to be able to only create one instance of the driver and carry that across several different classes "clients, invoicing, estimates, etc. as I group my tests by their functionalities.  In the end I would just click to run an instance of webdriver and it covers everything.

However I keep getting new instances of a webdriver for each class I run (in this case 2).  Here are my samples below:

My driver creator:

```
public class DriverObject
{

    protected static IWebDriver Driver { get; } = new ChromeDriver(options());

    public static ChromeOptions options()
    {
        ChromeOptions info = new ChromeOptions();
        info.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
        return info;
    }
}
```

My setup class that collects the driver:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SetupTestC : Release.DriverObject
{

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.yahoo.com");
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        Driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

One of the test classes:

```
public partial class Client : TestStructure.SetupTestC
{

    [Test]
    public void test1()
    {
        By searchBtn = By.Id("uh-search-box");
        Driver.FindElement(searchBtn).Click();
        Driver.FindElement(searchBtn).SendKeys("This is a test search");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

    }
}
```

My other test class:

```
class Invoices : TestStructure.SetupTestC
{
    [Test]
    public void test2()
    {
        Assert.True(false);
    }
}
```

I tried using a Category tag for NUnit 3 but it doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: It looks to me like you need to pass your `driver` object to your test classes to keep the same instance.

Comment: Here is a good read, this will help you achieve what you need:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Nunit runs all tests from one assemly in a seperate Appdomain per default. If you run two tests from two assemblies your static members will also get initialized twice.

Comment: This is opposed to in TestNG and Java where you can simply use @BeforeSuite and it encapsulates the whole test framework.  That is the direction I am trying to go in unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Make your test classes to extend a common class that contains a getter for your WebDriver initialized by default or by a method implementation.

`public class XYXYtest : Main {
    // your stuff here with access to single-instance shared WebDriver object.
}`

`public class Main {
    public WebDriver driver = yourConnectionMethod();
    // more common stuff if you need to.
}`

I think it's cleaner than passing the object to the methods, rather than the methods in this class extending main should use driver extended object.